# Why doesn't IE opens Outlook with the /a (attachment) param if the mailto attachment param is specified?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, outlook, attachment, mailto

If I can guarantee that the client machine uses Outlook and the browser is IE9+, is there a way to construct the mailto so that the command like invocation of Outlook includes the /a so it will use the attachment param of the mailto?

So say the mailto looks like

```
function emailFile() {
    var contentArea = "This is the text";
    var subject = "This is the subject";
    var href = 'mailto:?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + contentArea + '&attachment="e:/large.jpg"' ;
    location.href = href;
}
```

Why isn't command line outlook opened from the jQuery code with the /a param that Outlook expects? There are so many questions about mailto attachments on the web that I know there must be an issue but Outlook command line provides a switch so why isn't the switch used in this scenario?

Or if it does work, what are the prereqs and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that mean there is a way to email with attachments from jQuery/Javascript to Outlook?